# While looping a range of integers, convert integer representing number of months to the number of years and months

Tags: php, time, division, data-conversion, modulo

I am using a for loop to display numbers 1-60:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++)
```

within the loop, i want to be able to show the number of years and months. for example:

```
1 month
2 months
3 month
...
1 year
1 year 1 month
1 year 2 month
```

and so on...

I tried this:

```
if (!is_float($i / 12)) {
    $years = $i/12;
} else {
    $years = 'no';
}
```

This shows 1 on the 12 month, 2 on 24 months but not the in between.

Comment: Use `$i % 12` to get the remainder for in between.

Comment: in place if if(!is_float($i/12)) { ?

Comment: No, it's a separate part of the code. `$months = $i % 12`.

Comment: Why is it `nothing` for `1` and `2`? Shouldn't it be `1 month` and `2 months`?

Comment: sorry, i meant i want to display 1 month, 2 months, 3 months, ..., 1 year, 1 year 1 month, 1 year 2 month and so on..

Comment: Edit the question to say what you meant.

Comment: okay, check my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following solution to complete my code with help from @scaisEdge

```
for($i=0; $i<=60; $i++) {
    if(!is_float($i/12)) {
        $years = floor($i / 12).' Year';
        $years = $years.($years > 1 ? 's' : '');
        if($years == 0) {
            $years = '';
        }
    }
    $months = ' '.($i % 12).' Month';
    if($months == 0 or $months > 1) {
        $months = $months.'s';
    }

    $display = $years.''.$months;
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"';
    if($result["warrenty"] == $i) {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '>'.$display.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `!is_float($i/12)` test? That only executes it when `$i` is an exact multiple of 12. Why don't you want to set `$years` when in other cases?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `%` and `/` for the integer part and the rest of division
try  this loop for show the result

```
 for($i=1; $i<=60; $i++){

        echo 'year = ' . floor($i/12) . ' month = ' .$i%12 . '<br />';

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function yearfm($months)
{
  $str = '';

  if(($y = round(bcdiv($months, 12))))
  {
    $str .= "$y Year".($y-1 ? 's' : null);
  }
  if(($m = round($months % 12)))
  {
    $str .= ($y ? ' ' : null)."$m Month".($m-1 ? 's' : null);
  }
  return empty($str) ? false : $str;
}
for($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++)
{
  var_dump(yearfm($x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution 1:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=60; $i++) {
    $output = [];
    if ($i >= 12) {
        $years    = ($i - $i % 12) / 12;
        $output[] = $years > 1 ? $years . ' years' : $years . ' year';
    }

    if ($i % 12 > 0) {
        $monthsRest = $i % 12;
        $output[]   = $monthsRest > 1 ? $monthsRest . ' months' : $monthsRest . ' month';
    }
    echo implode(' ', $output);
}
```

another solution 2:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=60; $i++) {
    $output    = [];
    $startDate = new DateTime();
    $endDate   = new DateTime('+' . $i . ' months');

    $interval  = $startDate->diff($endDate);
    $years     = $interval->format('%y');
    $months    = $interval->format('%m');

    if ($years > 0) {
        $output[] = $years > 1 ? $years . ' years' : $years . ' year';
    }

    if ($months > 0) {
        $output[] = $months > 1 ? $months . ' months' : $months . ' month';
    }

    echo implode(' ', $output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cleanly written printing script, pass the integer value of the division of the counter by 12 and the modulus/remainder of the same division to `printf()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ncMK3))

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 60; ++$i) {
    printf("Year: %d, Month: %d\n", intdiv($i, 12), $i % 12);
}
```

Output:

```
Year: 0, Month: 1
Year: 0, Month: 2
...
Year: 0, Month: 11
Year: 1, Month: 0
Year: 1, Month: 1
Year: 1, Month: 2
...
```

---

If you want to handle plurality in your output, then cache the calculated values and check if they equal `1` to determine the inclusion of `s`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Cu1h1))

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 60; ++$i) {
    $years = intdiv($i, 12);
    $months = $i % 12;
    printf(
        "%d year%s, %d month%s\n",
        $years,
        $years !== 1 ? 's' : '',
        $months,
        $months !== 1 ? 's' : ''
    );
}
```

Output:

```
0 years, 1 month
0 years, 2 months
...
0 years, 11 months
1 year, 0 months
1 year, 1 month
1 year, 2 months
...
```

---

Finally, if you want to omit `0` value units, conditionally accumulate non-zero results into a temporary array and present by imploding with a delimiter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y7b5N))

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 60; ++$i) {
    $result = [];
    $years = intdiv($i, 12);
    if ($years) {
        $result[] = $years . ' year' . ($years !== 1 ? 's' : '');
    }
    $months = $i % 12;
    if ($months) {
        $result[] = $months . ' month' . ($months !== 1 ? 's' : '');
    }
    echo implode(', ', $result) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 month
2 months
...
11 months
1 year
1 year, 1 month
1 year, 2 months
...
```